# Sourcetree: how to ignore submodules

Tags: git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree

Sourcetree seems to be pulling in submodules by default, something the CLI doesn't do(by dafault). How do I stop sourcetree from pulling the submodules?

Comment: When you say "pulling in" do you just mean showing the name of the submodule?  Could you attach a screen shot for what you see in the Sourcetree GUI vs what you see in command line?